# D3js Angular Directive Lots of Repeating Code on Re-Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm a little new to using D3, and trying to create a scatter-plot. I seem to have lots of repeating code due for window resize, and rendering on data updates. I'm not sure if it's the nature of D3 and updating data or if I'm overlooking a pretty obvious update pattern.

The directive seems lengthy, but only because I have similar code repeated in `updateWindow()` (for browser resize), `render` (for the initial rendering and inserting SVG elements, and `update` (for updating the element attributes when the data changes). Here is my directive, currently:

```
app.directive('scatterPlot', function ($window, inputService, dataHandler) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            input: '=',
            display: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, array) {

            var container = angular.element(document.querySelector('section.output'))[0];
            var filterCount = 0;
            var data = undefined;

            // ********** ********** ************ // 
            // ********* ************ *********** //  
            // ******** ************** ********** //  
            // ******* **************** ********* //  
            // ******* WATCH AND RENDER ********* // 
            scope.$on('inputChange', function(event, isDeleted, isEmpty, isComplete, id, value) {
                // CHECK FOR MATCHES //
                console.log('event: ', event);
                console.log('isDeleted: ', isDeleted, ', isEmpty: ', isEmpty, ', isComplete: ', isComplete, ', id: ', id, ', value: ', value);
                if (isDeleted) {
                    filterCount -= 1;
                    console.log('filterCount: ', filterCount);
                } else {
                    if (filterCount == 0) {
                        dataHandler.matchQuery(id, value).then(function(matches) {
                            data = matches;
                            filterCount += 1;
                            return render(matches);
                        });  
                    } else {
                        dataHandler.matchQuery(id, value, data).then(function(matches) {
                            data = matches;
                            filterCount += 1;
                            if (filterCount > 0) {
                                return update(data);
                            }

                        });   
                    }  
                }
            });

            var formatAsMillions = d3.format('$' + "s");
            var formatAsYears = function(d) { return Math.floor(d/365) + ' Years'; };

            function update(data) {

                var el = element[0];

                var margin = {
                    top: container.clientHeight / 12, 
                    right: container.clientWidth / 7, 
                    bottom: container.clientHeight / 5, 
                    left: container.clientWidth / 11
                };

                var w = (container.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.9;
                var h = (container.clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom) * 0.9;

                var input = data;

                var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
                    .range([0, w])
                    .nice();

                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
                    .range([h, 0])
                    .nice();

                var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["effective"]; })])
                    .range([2, 10]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(5)
                    .tickFormat(formatAsMillions);

                var max= xScale.domain()[1];

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient('left')
                    .ticks(8)
                    .tickFormat(formatAsYears)
                    .tickFormat(function (days) {
                          if (max < 50) {
                            return d3.format("2.1f")(days) + " d";
                          }
                          else if (max >= 50 && max < 100) {
                            return d3.format("2.1f")(days/7) + " w";
                          }
                          else if (max >= 100 && max < 500) {
                            return d3.format("2.1f")(days/(365/12)) + " m";
                          }
                          else if (max >= 500){
                            return d3.format("2.1f")(days/365) + " y";
                          } 
                     });

                // *********** //
                // SVG ELEMENT //  
                var svg = d3.select('svg')
                    .attr('class', 'scatter')
                    .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

                // add X axis
                d3.select('.xAxis')
                    .data(input)
                    .remove()
                    .exit()

                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'xAxis')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
                    .call(xAxis);

                // add Y axis
                d3.select('.yAxis')
                    .data(input)
                    .remove()
                    .exit()

                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'yAxis')
                    .call(yAxis);

                // DATA JOIN
                // Join new data with old elements, if any.  
                var circle = d3.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(input, function(d) {return d.id;})
                    .remove()
                    .exit();

                // UPDATE
                // Update old elements as needed.
                circle.attr('class', 'update')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); }); 
            }

            function render(matches) {
                console.log(matches.length);
                // ********** ********** ************ // 
                // ********* ************ *********** //  
                // ******** ************** ********** //  
                // ******** **************** ******** //  
                // ******** BASIC ATTRIBUTES ******** //
                var input = matches;
                var el = element[0];
                var effectiveScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, d3.max(input, function(d) {return d["effective"]; }) ])
                    .range(["#35ca98", "#029765", "#006432", "#001700"]);

                var margin = {
                    top: container.clientHeight / 12, 
                    right: container.clientWidth / 7, 
                    bottom: container.clientHeight / 5, 
                    left: container.clientWidth / 11
                };

                var w = (container.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.9;
                var h = (container.clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom) * 0.9;



                var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
                    .range([0, w])
                    .nice();

                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
                    .range([h, 0])
                    .nice();

                var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["effective"]; })])
                    .range([2, 15]);

                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(5)
                    .tickFormat(formatAsMillions);

                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient('left')
                    .ticks(8)
                    .tickFormat(formatAsYears);

                // *********** //
                // SVG ELEMENT //  
                var svg = d3.select(el)
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('class', 'scatter')
                    .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

                // add X axis
                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'xAxis')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
                    .call(xAxis);

                // add Y axis
                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'yAxis')
                    .call(yAxis);

                //Create the tooltip label
                var tooltip = d3.select('body')
                    .append('div')
                    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
                    .style('position', 'absolute')
                    .style('z-index', '10')
                    .style('visibility', 'hidden')

                // add circles in group
                var circles = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class','circles')
                    .attr('clip-path','url(#chart-area)');

                // add individual circles
                var circle = circles.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(input, function(d) {return d.id;})
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); })
                    .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return effectiveScale(d["effective"])})
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
                        return tooltip.text(d["technology"]);
                     })
                    .on("mousemove", function(){ return tooltip.style("top",
                        (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
                    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})

                    // NEW SCOPE VALUE ON CLICK //
                    .on('click', function(d) {
                        scope.display = d;
                        console.log(d);
                        scope.$apply();
                        return d;
                    });


                // append clip path
                svg.append('clipPath')
                    .attr('id','chart-area')
                    .append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'rect')
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', 0)
                    .attr('width', w)
                    .attr('height', h);

                // add text
                svg.selectAll('text')
                    .data(input, function(d) {return d.id;})
                    .enter()
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'label')
                    .attr('clip-path','url(#chart-area)')
                    .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]) - rScale(d["effective"]) - 9; })
                    //.text(function(d) { return d["technology"]; });


                // ********** ********** ************ // 
                // ********* ************ *********** //  
                // ******** ************** ********** //  
                // ******** ************** ********** //  
                // ******** UPDATE WINDOW *********** //
                angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                    updateWindow();
                });    


                function updateWindow() {

                    var w = container.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
                    var h = (container.clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom) * 0.9;

                    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
                        .range([0, w])
                        .nice();

                    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
                        .range([h, 0])
                        .nice();

                    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xScale)
                        .orient('bottom')
                        .ticks(5)
                        .tickFormat(formatAsMillions);


                    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(yScale)
                        .orient('left')
                        .ticks(8)
                        .tickFormat(formatAsYears);

                    // add X axis
                    d3.select('.xAxis')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
                        .call(xAxis);

                    // add Y axis
                    d3.select('.yAxis')
                        .call(yAxis);

                    /// adjust svg element width/height
                    d3.select('.scatter')
                        .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .select('g')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
                        .attr('width', w + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

                    // adjust circle location
                    d3.select('.circles')
                        .attr('clip-path','url(#chart-area)')
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                        .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                        .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); });

                    // adjust clip path
                    d3.select('.rect')
                        .attr('x', 0)
                        .attr('y', 0)
                        .attr('width', w)
                        .attr('height', h);     
                }
            };     
        }
    };
});
```

Is there a common update pattern for reusing some of the same declarations here?

Comment: I didn't go through the whole thing.  Are you trying to just resize the chart? Or are you trying to actually adjust the chart, such as downsample the data points or have different scale on axis?  If you just want to resize the chart, you can do this in CSS easily by placing the chart in a container and using preserveAspectRatio and viewBox (without a height and width).   To make the height of the container proportionate to the width, use an intrinsic ratio: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video.  It's all CSS and requires no scripting.

Comment: What @jme11 said :-) Also, it looks like this directive is updating DOM elements elsewhere on the page? That's not a good idea if you want any kind of re-usability. Within the directive link function, you should only update the DOM under the ```element``` that is passed to the link function.

Comment: @jme11 I'm just trying to resize the chart. I'll take a look at the link you sent, thanks for the tip. Also, I'll separate out the other DOM manipulation on the page, thanks. As far as updating the data, taking a look at "render" and "update", is there a way I can make this code more DRY and concise?

Comment: I just found the link I was looking for: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/.  This will take you head to toe on using the technique I explained.  Also, if you have a chart with millions of ticks on it and scaling it down crowds everything and makes it look messy, my other trick is to set a class on the ticks and then use :nth-child pseudo class to hide every n ticks in a media query.

Comment: @jme11 I've tinkered with viewBox and preserverAspectRatio before, and couldn't get it working. Do these attributes make it possible to dynamically resize the graph when the browser window is resized, or does it only adjust for the initial render?

Comment: In your `update` function the `.exit()` should be before the `.remove()`. If you want your code to be more DRY then keep staring at it and maybe it will happen...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. No thanks for the tip.